# Displaying a div when clicking on a link only works for the first one of a list

Tags: javascript

I am having a bit of trouble finding what is wrong with my code, it is supposed to display a hidden popUp when I click a link (id= lnkInfo) on a div, the problem is that it only works for the first div and not for the others on a list.

This is the code I was using to hide nd display:
JS

---

```
function displayPopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('hide','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' show';
}

function hidePopUp(pIdDivToShow){
var fElementDivToShow = document.getElementById(pIdDivToShow),
newClass ='';
newClass = fElementDivToShow.className.replace('show','');
fElementDivToShow.className = newClass + ' hide';
}
```

Said divs are created via php, as does the information that goes inside the pop up, so to show exactly what is going on I made a fiddle out of it with how it would look when I have two divs, the id of the lab divs is always the last one's id+1.

[Fiddle EDITED](http://jsfiddle.net/3UNnk/5/)

I know that I should use a class instead of a id, but doing so makes the JS part to malfunction, even if I use querySelector or getByClass.

Any help would be deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

So I was thinking something along these lines to do what was suggested and apply the changes to each element. Prettu sure that is not how I attach the array to the displayPopUp thou.

```
var elementoVerInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('lnkInfo'),
elementoBotonCerrar = document.getElementById('btnCerrar'); 

elementoVerInfo.addEventListener('click', function () {

    for (var i = 0 ; i < elementoVerInfo.length; i++) {
        elementoVerInfo[i].displayPopUp('popUpCorrecto1');
    };
});
```

Comment: ID's are unique, that's why it only works for the first one, there should be only one.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Updated the fiddle but now it doesn't even show the first one.

Comment: When you receive a collection of elements, you need to iterate the collection in a loop and apply the desired code to each element. This is pretty basic JavaScript.

Comment: And your HTML markup is invalid. Take care to match your closing tags properly.

Comment: @cookiemonster Sorry, I am started a little bit ago and mostly with basic HTML and the like >.< I'll get better!

Comment: I extracted those snippets of code out of the whole, so I may have left or brought something unwanted with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's must be unique.

You will have to change the id to a class and use something like `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: I already tried that but I think it has something to with there being more than one element with that class name thus making the variable an array (pure speculation based on my limited knowledge)